# What are some good ways of estimating 'approximate' semantic similarity between sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, machine-learning, data-mining, nltk

I have been looking at the nlp tag on SO for the past couple of hours and am confident I did not miss anything but if I did, please do point me to the question.

In the mean time though, I will describe what I am trying to do. A common notion that I observed on many posts is that semantic similarity is difficult. For instance, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037832/semantic-similarity-between-sentences) post, the accepted solution suggests the following:

```
First of all, neither from the perspective of computational 
linguistics nor of theoretical linguistics is it clear what 
the term 'semantic similarity' means exactly. .... 
Consider these examples:

Pete and Rob have found a dog near the station.
Pete and Rob have never found a dog near the station.
Pete and Rob both like programming a lot.
Patricia found a dog near the station.
It was a dog who found Pete and Rob under the snow.

Which of the sentences 2-4 are similar to 1? 2 is the exact 
opposite of 1, still it is about Pete and Rob (not) finding a 
dog.
```

My high-level requirement is to utilize k-means clustering and categorize the text based on semantic similarity so all I need to know is whether they are an approximate match. For instance, in the above example, I am OK with classifying 1,2,4,5 into one category and 3 into another (of course, 3 will be backed up with some more similar sentences). Something like, find related articles, but they don't have to be 100% related.

I am thinking I need to ultimately construct vector representations of each sentence, sort of like its fingerprint but exactly what this vector should contain is still an open question for me. Is it n-grams, or something from the wordnet or just the individual stemmed words or something else altogether?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254627/what-tried-and-true-algorithms-for-suggesting-related-articles-are-out-there) thread did a fantastic job of enumerating all related techniques but unfortunately stopped just when the post got to what I wanted. Any suggestions on what is the latest state-of-the-art in this area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Latent Semantic Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_mapping) could be useful.  It's basically just yet another application of the [Singular Value Decomposition](http://www.uwlax.edu/faculty/will/svd/).  The [SVDLIBC](http://tedlab.mit.edu/~dr/SVDLIBC/) is a pretty nice C implementation of this approach, which is an oldie but a goodie, and there are even python binding in the form of [sparsesvd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sparsesvd).

Comment: A Python implementation of SVD for sparse matrices is also provided in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/) as `scikits.learn.utils.extmath.fast_svd`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try a topic modelling framework such as Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA). The idea there is that documents (in your case sentences, which might prove to be a problem) are generated from a set of latent (hidden) topics; LDA retrieves those topics, representing them by word clusters.

An [implementation of LDA in Python](http://nlp.fi.muni.cz/projekty/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) is available as part of the free Gensim package. You could try to apply it to your sentences, then run *k*-means on its output.

Comment: Yes, I think that LDA is all the rage now.