# Clustering web page titles on the basis of their meaning

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis

I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593030/what-are-some-good-ways-of-estimating-approximate-semantic-similarity-between). The code given here could not cluster topics like :

```
    "Number theory",
    "Finite field",
    "Rational number",
    "Continued fraction representation",
    "Floating point",
    "Mughal architecture"
```

All were in the same cluster.
What should I do to make the mathematics topics go into one cluster and others into their respective cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

You should feed the article texts to the clustering algorithm. The titles alone are much too sparse, they simply don't carry enough information to do the necessary statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that these titles were *in a language you don't know*, how would you proceed?

Without additional information, that is what a computer program faces. It does not have a chance of getting this right!

So you would need to either

- add additional information the similarity of words, e.g. based on WordNet
- add more text, such as the full articles