# How to find the semantic similarity between 2 sentences?

Tags: nlp

Please tell me some methods to find semantic similarity between sentences.

```
For example:

Sen1 :- Ram killed Ravan
Sen2 :- Sam was killed by Ravan
```

What is the similarity between both sentences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037832/semantic-similarity-between-sentences?rq=1 AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593030/what-are-some-good-ways-of-estimating-approximate-semantic-similarity-between?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods to find semantic similarity of sentences:
check vector representation models - Form word by Doc matrix and find cosine similarity between each dimensions.

```
check LSA (Latent Semantic Analysis)
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis

This method helps to give semantic similarity between words like vehicle and car. But, this is a bag of words model(BOW).