# measure relevance of a search term returned matched against results

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a PHP or MySQL function which will check how relevant a matching field is? Could it review the string and match against a percentage of characters?

For example I am doing a basic search script pulling back results but how can I make the more relevant results appear at the top?

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on your data and the type of searches that you are expecting. But basically, you could be looking for a fuzzy search. Soundex and Levenshtein distance are two of the many functions that you can use for string matches

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i am going to try this and come back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are asking a few complicated questions here. Mostly, I think you are looking for information retrieval techniques. Some answers are all over Stack OVerflow.

[What tried and true algorithms for suggesting related articles are out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254627/what-tried-and-true-algorithms-for-suggesting-related-articles-are-out-there) is great I think

You might want to use the [levenshtein distance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) if you are just looking for how closely a keyword matches an existing keyword.

I tried :P

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has a function MATCH
You can youse it like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST('search text')
```

So it will look within content how relevancy it is.
But you need to index field `content` to FULLTEXT which requires an table type "MYISAM".
The output will automaticly sorted ascending.

hope this helps

Comment: Nice idea...leave it with me for a bit